# Filter query according to the parameters Oracle

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, oracle

I have a query and in here i accept 3 parameters all the parameters are optional.But 
when one parameter comes the data will filter it with that parameter and when two
parameters comes data it need to be filtered from those two parameters.

In here all three parameters and if two parameters has a value then i pass the other parameter as a null

problem is when two parameters comes and anotherone is null not filtered in this query

my query like this.

```
string NewsQuery = @"SELECT N.NID,N.NEWS,N.REFSEC,N.AUTHRIZED,N.USERID,N.REFERENCENO
       FROM TBL_NEWS N
       WHERE N.REFERENCENO=:ReferenceNo AND N.NID =:Nstatus AND N.USERID=:StaffNo";

 cmd = db.GetSqlStringCommand(NewsQuery);
 db.AddInParameter(cmd, "ReferenceNo", DbType.String, null);
 db.AddInParameter(cmd, "Nstatus", DbType.String, NewsStatus);
 db.AddInParameter(cmd, "StaffNo", DbType.String, userno);
```

Comment: I think you should add `C#` tag also

Comment: Use a Stored Procedure to achieve what you're doing right now, it'll reap better fruit in cases like yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add OR clauses to your query to allow the *NULL* parameter values.

string NewsQuery = @"SELECT N.NID,N.NEWS,N.REFSEC,N.AUTHRIZED,N.USERID,N.REFERENCENO FROM TBL_NEWS N WHERE (N.REFERENCENO=:ReferenceNo OR :ReferenceNo IS NULL) AND (N.NID =:Nstatus OR :Nstatus IS NULL) AND (N.USERID=:StaffNo OR :StaffNo IS NULL) ";